# need help BOOTING UBUNTU from EXTERNAL HDD

Tags: boot

I have installed UBUBTU to my external hard drive.

It is installed as a dual boot from my laptop.When i try to boot from another PC or LAPTOP, I can not boot UBUBTU from my external HDD.

I want a complete installation on my external HDD so that i can plug my USB HDD to any PC and run UBUNTU.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a detailed description of the problem you are encountering including the exact text of all error messages.

Comment: Is it OK without disk encryption? In that case there is an easy way. Otherwise it is more complicated, easiest if you can unplug, disconnect or otherwise disable the internal drive while you install Ubuntu to the external drive. See this link (the answers are relevant for different cases), [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step).

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? Either way you need grub installed to external drive. If UEFI, Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs to ESP - efi system partition on internal drive. You have to manually create an ESP on external drive. If BIOS you have to use Something Else and install grub to external drive (that choice does not work with UEFI). One of several work arounds. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
 If you have ESP on external for UEFI, just reinstall grub to external drive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. Just Change the boot sequence to point to External Hard disk. It differs from machine to machine based on your BIOS settings.
Example: [see Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-boot-order-in-bios-2624528#:%7E:text=A%20complete%20tutorial%20on%20changing%20the%20boot%20order,from%20Hard%20Drive%20shown%20in%20...%20More%20items)